External direct sum $U_1\oplus U_2$ isomorphic to $U_1+U_2$ does not necessarily imply that $U_1\cap U_2 = \{0\}$
Let $V$ be a vector space (not necessarily finite-dimensional) and let $U_1,U_2\subset V$ be subspaces. If $U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}$, then the surjective linear map $\phi\colon U_1\oplus U_2 \to U_1+U_2$ defined by $\phi((u_1,u_2))=u_1+u_2$ is also injective and thus $U_1\oplus U_2 \simeq U_1+U_2$.
If V is finite-dimensional, then $U_1\cap U_2 \neq \{0\}$ is a necessary condition for $U_1\oplus U_2 \simeq U_1+U_2$ to hold true.
However, if V is infinite-dimensional, $U_1\cap U_2 \neq \{0\}$ is not necessarily true if $U_1\oplus U_2 \simeq U_1+U_2$ and I am looking for a counterexample to demonstrate this.
Any help would be much appreciated!

You'll not succeed since it's not true.

@ancientmathematician Wow ok... thank you very much for pointing this out! Could you perhaps provide a counterexample? I was given the following exercise: Prove that $U_1\oplus U_2 \simeq U_1+U_2$ if and only if $U_1\cap U_2={0}$. I guess that's true only in the finite-dimensional case then?

[I take it that $U_1\oplus U_2$ refers to the external direct sum.]
Let $V$ be the vector space of real sequences, $\{(v_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}\}$.
Let $U_1:= \{v\in V\mid v_{2i+1}=0 \text{  for all}\ i\geqslant 0\}$.
Let $U_2:= \{v\in V\mid v_{2i}=0 \text{  for all}\ i\geqslant 1\}$.
We have that $U_1\cap U_2=\{v\in V\mid v_{i}=0 \text{  for all}\ i\geqslant 1\}\ne \{0\}$.
Then it is straightforward to prove that $U_1\simeq U_2\simeq U_1+ U_2\simeq U_1\oplus U_2\simeq V$.

There are two related but distinct questions here:

Is the map $U_1 \oplus U_2 \to V$ given by $(u_1, u_2) \mapsto u_1 + u_2$ an isomorphism onto $U_1 + U_2$? Equivalently, is this map injective (since the image is clearly $U_1 + U_2$)?
Is there any isomorphism between $U_1 \oplus U_2$ and $U_1 + U_2$?

Clearly if it the answer to 1 is yes then the answer to 2 is yes. But we can pin down exactly when each of these happens:

When $U_ 1\cap U_2 = 0$.
When $U_1 \cap U_2 = 0$ or at least one of $U_1$ and $U_2$ is infinite dimensional.

To see this, you can check that the kernel or null space of the map in 1 is given exactly by $\{(v, -v) \mid v \in U_1 \cap U_2\}$ and therefore $\dim (U_1 + U_2) = \dim U_1 + \dim U_2 - \dim (U_1 \cap U_2)$ if both $U_1$ and $U_2$ are finite dimensional (which governs the answer to 2, since two vector spaces are isomorphic exactly when the have the same dimension). If either is infinite dimensional then the dimension both $U_1$ and $U_2$ is $\max (\dim U_1, \dim U_2)$, so the answer to 2 is yes.
